# Is there is a way to collec the logs of terminated/closed logs

Tags: kubernetes-pod

I am relatively new to Docker and Kubernetes technologies. My requirement is to collect the logs of
terminated logs/closed logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all container logs on respective nodes.

For that, there is multiple ways you can export the logs.

You can read more at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/

If you want to save the logs from the container also you can go for the side approach also or from the file system of the node.

Answer (score 0):

from kubernetes you cannot get logs from a pod that is not in running state. But you can identify the respective container on the worker node using  `docker ps -a | grep <nameofthepod>` then use `docker logs <containerID>`.